# How to set the os.environ for the nova-api?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I want to set the some variable in nova-api.

Which is the best way to set that? (in `nova.conf` or in other file?)

I can set in `/etc/nova/nova.conf` and get the value of that variable in the api. But is there any other way to set environment variable for the API? I want to access by `os.environ` in the script. (Is this the right way to access or not?)

As per my knowledge, for the `wsgi` we have to set in the apache's config file. But for nova I cant find the file :(.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: SetEnv in Apache does not set os.environ for mod_wsgi if when you said 'wsgi' you actually meant mod_wsgi.

Comment: I am expecting first reply from @GrahamDumpleton :). I set the env variable from the `init.d` script. In the scrip `/etc/init.d/openstack-nova-api` one file is used `/etc/sysconfig/$prog` so we set the `export` variable in this file and got the reference later. Thx for your reply.

Comment: For Linux systems, one of the init.d files, set as normal shell variable usually works. If a traditional Apache Software Foundation distribution of Apache, would use the envvars file in same directory as Apache executable.

Comment: You can also just set os.environ at the start of the WSGI script file. For a lot of things where is only Python modules reading it, that is fine. Doing it in init.d/envars only needed if something like LANG/LC_ALL/LD_LIBRARY_PATH where needed on process start of Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the env variable from the init.d script. In the scrip `/etc/init.d/openstack-nova-api` one file is used `/etc/sysconfig/$prog` so we set the export variable in this file and got the reference later.